# Mysql Query search by latest date with group by

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my table structure

[image]

and this is my dataset

[image]

What I want is query that gets data ordered by date desc and group by id_patient

so the result in the dataset example should be like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This doesn't sound like a PHP issue.

Comment: Show text directly in your post instead of links to images. Where's your code/query?

Comment: your question has the answer itself. doesn't seems to be appropriate question

Comment: Have you tried to do that yourself? If yes, please edit your question and put the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with `limit` clause with `subquery` since you have `PK` :

```
select *
from table t
where id = (select t1.id
            from table t1
            where t1.id_patient = t.id_patient
            order by t1.date desc
            limit 1
           );
```

However, if single `patient` has multiple same *dates* then this would produce only single records based on `date`.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * from rdv a JOIN (SELECT id_patient,MAX(date) date FROM rdv GROUP by id_patient ) b on a.id_patient = b.id_patient and a.date = b.date

Answer (score 0):

If you want the latest record for each patient, then you are not looking for an aggregation.  I would often approach this with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.id_patient = t.id_patient);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 SELECT *
 FROM table 
 GROUP BY group by id_patient 
 ordered by DATE(date) desc;
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? How does this query return the `Description` column?

Comment: in this setion they want to "search by latest date with group by"
so if you want to return the description by latest date  you do it like this:
SELECT Description, COUNT(id)
FROM tab 
GROUP BY Date(dat);

Comment: What's that `COUNT` used for? The OP has not asked about counting anything

Comment: just to show  the amount of Description exists in this period

Comment: But how is this related to the question? Please add some explanation to your answer that covers why your query looks completely different compared to the queries in the other answers (for example, how does your query return the proper description - keep in mind that `GROUP BY` might select a random row to group by, and not as requested the one with the most recent date **grouped by patient id, not by date**)